# Is there a way to limit the number of items displayed in Kendo ui multiselect dropdown asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo ui multiselect with like 60 values shown in the dropdown. Is there a way to only show like 10 items in the dropdown rather than all 60?

```
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("multiselect")
        .AutoClose(false)
        .Filter("contains")
        .BindTo(list)
```

FYI - I'm not looking for the **MaxSelectedItems()** which limits the number of items that can be selected, rather looking to **limit the number of items that the dropdown of multiselect displays at a time**.
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Kendo UI's built-in virtualization to dynamically load items as needed

Comment: @RashidurRehman Is there any sample code or anything for that which i can use?

Comment: sure give me a moment i'll try an example code for you

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with JavaScript/jQuery with the following code:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var multiselect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var items = multiselect.dataSource.data().slice(0, 10);
            multiselect.setDataSource(items);
        })
    </script>
}
```

Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: it does limit the items shown in the dropdown. But as we are limiting the datasource itself here, when i'm searching for something in the multiselect it only checks within these 10 items in that datasouce, and hence not displaying other data.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kendo UI's built-in virtualization to dynamically load items as needed:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("multiselect")
    .AutoClose(false)
    .Filter("contains")
    .Virtualization(true) // Enable virtualization
    .DataTextField("text") // Specify data field for text display
    .DataValueField("value") // Specify data field for value
    .DataSource(
        url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "YourController")", // URL to fetch data
        dataType: "json",
        serverFiltering: true, // Enable server-side filtering (optional)
        pageSize: 10 // Set page size to 10 (initial number of items)
    )
)

// Your controller action to return data (JSON format):

public ActionResult GetData(int page, string filter)
{
    // Implement your logic to fetch the requested page of data based on "page" and "filter" parameters
    // return JSON data with "data" and "total" properties
}
```

Check this and let me know if it works for you?